# Jenkins and Gerrit integration with google repo scm

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, repo

I am writing because there is something not clear to me on how to configure jenkins to fetch from gerrit the changes for building my project.

There is a lot of tutorial / examples on the net related to how to connect all those piece of code.
But I didn't found any that explain what I want to do.
I think it's possible but... well. I'm not sure.

My setup:
I have a repo manifest that contains a lot of different modules of the final application. The app was written in this way because I can change a module and substitute it with another with similar code that do a different job. For example they can be personalization for different customers.

I setup a job in jenkins that catch every commit in each submodule.

I connected Jenkins to Gerrit and I can start the build with gerrit trigger.

It works and I can build my master and the current master.

My problem is that when I send a patch for review jenkins build the master, not the patch I sent. I would like to test the last patch before integrating it on master.

Modules cannot be built standalone because they are all connected in some way so I cannot check each part alone.

Someone was able to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Gerrit Trigger start the Jenkins job, you could execute the following to prepare the workspace before you execute the build:

1. Use "repo sync" to checkout all repositories
2. Use the GERRIT_PROJECT and GERRIT_REFSPEC Gerrit Trigger env variables and execute the following commands to checkout the patchset of the changed repository:

   cd $GERRIT_PROJECT

   git fetch https://*USER*@*SERVER*/a/$GERRIT_PROJECT $GERRIT_REFSPEC && git checkout FETCH_HEAD

   OR

   git fetch ssh://*USER*@*SERVER*:29418/$GERRIT_PROJECT $GERRIT_REFSPEC && git checkout FETCH_HEAD

Comment: thank you. I checked and a small modification of it worked. The modification is for fitting my environment. cd $GERRIT_PROJECT    
git fetch ssh://jenkins@$GERRIT_HOST:29418/$GERRIT_PROJECT $GERRIT_REFSPEC && git checkout FETCH_HEAD

Comment: Cool. I edited the answer to add the SSH option and the missing $GERRIT_PROJECT at the url.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set accordingly the "Repositories" > "Advanced.." > "Refspec" and the "Branches to build" > "Branch Specifier" fields in: Job > Configure > Source Code Management > Git

If you want to build the "master" branch then set:

```
Refspec = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

Branch Specifier = refs/heads/master
```

If you want to build the patchset then set:

```
Refspec = $GERRIT_REFSPEC:$GERRIT_REFSPEC

Branch Specifieer = $GERRIT_REFSPEC
```

Click on the "?" at the right of the field to see more details.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thank you for your reply. I see what you are telling here. But... Configure > Source Code Management > Git... I'm using a google repo CSM not git directly. So if my change is in a sub project, let's say in a sub git module of repo. I need to checkout all the google repo with repo sync but including the correct patch uploaded on gerrit. Is not your reply related to git and not to repo?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'll try to post another solution.

Answer (score 0):

See the [gerrit-trigger-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/blob/master/docs/README.adoc) man page:

```
repo init -u git://gerrit.mycompany.net/mymanifest.git
repo sync
repo download $GERRIT_PROJECT $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER/$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER
```

... does what you're looking for.